# signed 16-bit SSE average

Tags: c++, c, performance, sse

`_mm_avg_epu16` provides an average of two unsigned 16-bit integers via `PAVGW`.  Is converting to `float` and dividing by `2.` the only appropriate (optimal) way to use SSE to get <strike>a average of two signed 16-bit integers</strike> a "signed average that rounds up followed by inverting the top bit" (@Mysticial), or is there another way?

---

EDIT: Here's the code I'd like to optimize, so far all my attempts using SSE have been close but not exactly matching, usually surrounding problems w/ saturation/overflow-wrapping:

```
int16_t *a;
int16_t *b;
uint16_t *out;

out[i] = int((a[i] + b[i]) / 2.0f + 32768.5f)
```

Attempt #1:

```
const __m128i outputVal = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_avg_epu16(a, b),  _mm_set1_epi16(32768));
```

Attempt #2:

```
const __m128i sum = _mm_add_epi16(a, b);
const __m128i outputVal = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_srai_epi16(sum, 1), _mm_set1_epi16(32768));
```

Attempt #3:

```
const __m128 elt_offset = _mm_set1_ps(32768.5f);

const __m128 avg_divisor = _mm_set1_ps(2.f);

const __m128i eltSum = _mm_add_epi16(edgeRowElts, edgeInnerRowElts); /* eltSum = int((inputData[i] + inputData[i + (direction*x)]) */
const __m64 eltSumLow  = _mm_movepi64_pi64(eltSum); /* eltSumLow = (__m64) (0x0ffffffff & eltSum) */
const __m64 eltSumHigh = _mm_movepi64_pi64(_mm_srli_si128(eltSum, 8)); /* eltSumHigh = (__m64) (0x0ffffffff & (eltSum >> 64)) */

/* Lower */
__m128 eltSumF = _mm_cvtpi16_ps(eltSumLow); /* eltSumF = (float) eltSum; */

__m128 eltAvg  = _mm_div_ps(eltSumF, avg_divisor); /* eltAvg = eltSum / 2.0f */
__m128 eltAvgOffset = _mm_add_ps(eltAvg,  elt_offset); /* eltAvgOffset = eltAvg + 32768.5f */
const __m64 outputValLow  = _mm_cvtps_pi16(eltAvgOffset); /* outputVal = (short) eltAvgOffset */

/* Upper */
eltSumF = _mm_cvtpi16_ps(eltSumHigh); /* eltSumF = (float) eltSum; */

eltAvg  = _mm_div_ps(eltSumF, avg_divisor); /* eltAvg = eltSum / 2.0f */
eltAvgOffset = _mm_add_ps(eltAvg,  elt_offset); /* eltAvgOffset = eltAvg + 32768.5f */
const __m64 outputValHigh = _mm_cvtps_pi16(eltAvgOffset); /* outputVal = (short) eltAvgOffset */

__m128i outputVal = _mm_slli_si128(_mm_movpi64_epi64(outputValHigh), 8); /* outputVal = (outputValHigh << 64); */
outputVal = _mm_or_si128(outputVal, _mm_movpi64_epi64(outputValLow)); /* outputVal = outputVal | (outputValLow); */
```

Comment: Huh?  Why would you want to convert to float at all?  Put your (array of) 16-bit integers in memory, load them into an `__m128i`, call `_mm_avg_epu16`, then unpack the `__m128i`.

Comment: Deleted my answer since it looks like you need to handle overflow as well as proper rounding.

Comment: It looks like you want a signed average that rounds up followed by inverting the top bit. One way is to do a sign-extension to 32-bit to do the computation. Then convert back. There's an SSE4.1 instruction for the extension, but not backwards. So you'll need some shuffling logic.

Comment: Small thing, adding by `32768` is the same as xoring by `32768`. On a current Intel processor, you might want to prefer xor over add since xor can be done in all of the execution units. (whereas addition can only be done in a couple of them)

Comment: @Mysticial, so that helps some pipeline scheduling stuff?

Comment: Correct. It gives more flexibility to issue the instructions. If all your addition execution units are busy, then you won't be able to issue another one. But if you're doing an xor instead, then you can issue it to the multiplier if it's idle. (On current Intel processors, the SSE add and SSE multiply units can both do xors.)

Comment: I just took a look at the Sandy Bridge docs, and it looks like I'm slightly off. But the idea is still the same. Addition can only be done on 2 of the 3 execution units. But xor can be done on all 3 of them.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "round up followed by inverting the top bit" stuff means, but can't you use the well-known bit twiddle `(x&y)+((x^y)>>1)` for this? That one calculates the average without overflows and should translate to SSE instructions very easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand all the requirements here, but it seems that:

```
a = _mm_add_epi16(a, _mm_set1_epi16(32768));
b = _mm_add_epi16(b, _mm_set1_epi16(32768));
outputVal = _mm_avg_epu16(a, b);
```

should give you everything apart from the rounding up requirement.

If so then it shouldn't be to hard to fix up the rounding after the fact:

```
round = _mm_xor_si128(a, b);
round = _mm_and_si128(round, _mm_set1_epi16(1));
outputVal = _mm_add_epi16(outputVal, round);
```

Comment: `_mm_avg_epu16` already takes care of rounding. It's equivalent to `(a + b + 1) / 2`

Comment: OP wants rounding up though, not round to nearest.

Comment: It's already rounding up. The possibilities are as follows: both arguments are even or odd - no rounding takes place; one of the arguments is even, the other odd - the average (XXX.5) is rounded up due to the `+ 1` part.

Comment: Yes, that's correct for the positive case - IIRC though this fix is needed for the negative case, but it's been a while since I looked at this.